# PC won't boot with more than one monitor plugged in, but once booted, works perfectly with multiple monitors

Tags: boot, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, power-supply, nvidia-geforce

So my graphics card is an asus nvidia geforce gtx 750ti, and works perfectly with multiple screens. The problem is that the computer will not boot with more than one monitor plugged in, but after it is booted (with 1 screen), I can then plug in another two screens (2 monitors and a TV; 3 in total) without any problems. What could the problem be? I have always had the latest drivers by the way. My problem is very similar to these two posts:

http://forums.hexus.net/pc-hardware-components/92256-pc-wont-boot-up-2-monitors-plugged.html

http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1893699/multiple-screens-computer-boot.html

The bios screen loads fine, and even the windows loading screen (windows 7 and now 10), but the screen turns black at the login screen (I never am able to see it).

When I first got the graphics card, it would boot with multiple screens, but after about a month or two, this problem started occurring. Since then, I have been unplugging my second monitor when booting the pc and then plugging it in after the computer is on (for about a year…). I think that it might be my power supply, but it is a 350W supply: PS-6351-2 so it should be ok. The box for the graphics card says it recommends 400W power supply, but online says 300W (on nvidia's website).

So what is the problem? The graphics card or the PSU? Does the PSU not give enough power at the very beginning, causing the gpu to turn off? Is my GPU defective, and needs more than 350W? It has a 3 year limited warranty, so maybe nvidia would help me out? I don’t mind buying a new PSU but I don’t want to put in all this effort and have the same problem come up.

Help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Unlikely to be your PSU since you can connect the additional displays after login without issue. Try logging in, connecting all displays, and then running some benchmark or stress testing applications to make sure though.

Comment: I agree with the above comment that if your PSU is underpowered it shouldn't work at all, not just if the second monitor is plugged in while booting. Also, the 750TI is extremely efficient - Tom's hardware measured it consuming 9W with three monitors while idling and only 62W while gaming. This is inline with my own measurements of power usage. 350W seems low for a desktop computer, but we can assume ~70W for your cpu, ~30W for the gfx card, 3W each for the HDD and RAM, 40W for the mobo, ~10W for fans, etc. This would only be about 160 watts. It might help if you gave us your specs.